# JJWT parse dont fail if SigningKey is slightly different

Tags: java, jwt, jjwt

I try to create JWT token

```
final String jws = Jwts.builder()
            .claim("rainId", rainId.toString())
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, TextCodec.BASE64.decode("jwtSecretKey"))
            .compact();
```

Then I try to parse it

```
Jws<Claims> jwsClaims = Jwts.parser()
                .require("rainId", rainId.toString())
                .setSigningKey(TextCodec.BASE64.decode("jwtSecretKey1"))
                .parseClaimsJws(jws);
```

As you can see `SigningKey` is slightly different, so I expect that parser will fail, but it doesnt happen. It happen only if `SigningKey` in parser have very big difference. For example "jwtSecretKey1111111111111111111111111111111" or "dsfdsfdsfdsfds". Can some one explain why parser not fail if `SigningKey` in parser is slightly different?

I use

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
  <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't seem to be using the API properly.

Both `signWith()` and `setSigningKey()` methods expect a Base64-encoded String as input. But you are invoking `TextCodec.BASE64.decode("...")`.

Both `jwtSecretKey` and `jwtSecretKey1` don't look like Base64-encoded strings. However, if you attempt to decode them, they will *produce the same output*:

```java
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(TextCodec.BASE64.decode("jwtSecretKey")));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(TextCodec.BASE64.decode("jwtSecretKey1")));
```

```
[-113, 11, 82, 121, -54, -34, -76, -89, -78]
[-113, 11, 82, 121, -54, -34, -76, -89, -78]
```

And that's why the signature validation doesn't fail.

You should use `TextCodec.BASE64.encode("...")` instead, as shown below:

```java
String jws = Jwts.builder()
        .claim("rainId", rainId.toString())
        .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, TextCodec.BASE64.encode("jwtSecretKey"))
        .compact();

Jws<Claims> jwsClaims = Jwts.parser()
        .require("rainId",rainId.toString())
        .setSigningKey(TextCodec.BASE64.encode("jwtSecretKey1"))
        .parseClaimsJws(jws);
```